# The ScrollViewer does not scroll

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I would like to have an interface with 3 components one next to the other. 
The first would be a ListView and the two others being Grids.

Since the components will overflow on the right, I want to put them in a ScrollViewer.
I did not succeed. I tried to do a really simple example to try, but even the example fails.

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600" Height="400">
        <StackPanel Width="1200" Height="400" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Border Background="AntiqueWhite" Width="400" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
            <Border Background="Blue" Width="400" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Border Background="LimeGreen" Width="400" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

As you can see, the ScrollViewer is Inside a Grid. 
What did I miss?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try settings these properties on the scroll viewer:-

```
 <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ZoomMode="Disabled" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600" Height="400">
    <StackPanel Width="1200" Height="400" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Border Background="AntiqueWhite" Width="400" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
        <Border Background="Blue" Width="400" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Border Background="LimeGreen" Width="400" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

That works for me normally!

Comment: can you suggest me a method to scroll using scrollviewer for the touch input.