# Scrollviewer doesn't scroll with touch

Tags: xaml, windows-8, scroll, scrollviewer

So I have come to that point where I am saying to myself over and over again I am missing some basic stuff.
I have a ScrollViewer with a RichTextBlock that [converts HTML to the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729540/convert-simple-html-to-a-richtextblock).

Everything shows up as expected but I can't scroll! I had the VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Hidden but I have taken that out. After seeing [this anwsear in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332867/the-scrollviewer-does-not-scroll) I have stoped with the following code:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" 
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
    VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
    ZoomMode="Disabled" 
    Padding="52" 
    Background="#60000000" >

    <RichTextBlock rtbx:Properties.Html="{Binding TextHTML}"
         TextAlignment="Justify" 
         FontSize="20" />

</ScrollViewer>
```

It also seems that the [PanningMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.panningmode.aspx) is not avaiable in Windows 8 but I belive that it is still the expected behaviour to scroll with the touch.

I have tried to put the ManipulationMode to All in the ScrollViewer and also tried to set to none in the RichTextBlock. However, I got no sucess with those approaches.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot which show what you get?

Comment: I have text and it shows the scroll on the right. Everything shows as expected. I can scroll using the scroll bar (with a mouse - actually I have some hard time doing that since the RichTextBlock overrides the cursor and I can only select the scroll bar in the right edge) but I can't scroll using the touch.

Comment: I had some troubles with the scrollviewer and text too. If I remember right I had to put a panel inside the scrollviewer and then the text inside the panel

Comment: I have tried to put a `Grid` inside and I had no success :(

Comment: Your XAML looks ok at first glance. Try to remove manipulationmode from RTB and set ishittestvisible to false.

Comment: I have removed the ManipulationMode from the RTB and it is the same. With `isHitTestVisible` set to false I cant scroll with the touch OR the mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the manipulation modes and isolating the problem and simplifing the "options" I was using led me to the conclusion that the ScrollViewer wasn't the issue.

The problem was: I had was a Control that was on top of the ScrollViewer that was hidden (opacity = 0). This Control swallowed all the events that I was needing in the ScrollViewer. Basic mistake.

I had to put the Visibility equals to Collapsed.